# Why does findOrCreateUser promise to return a user object?

Tags: node.js, everyauth

The `findOrCreateUser` function expects a user object returned. Why is this? What does it do with it?

Does it merely read and store the user's id for later reference?

Also, why doesn't it have a callback? Otherwise isn't it going to block whilst the code goes to the database?

Comment: Some insight.... https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `findOrCreateUser` is pseudo-code, so you can define your own method to be chained in everyauth's process.

Comment: Sure... chain it in but why does it want me to return a user object?